# how to add another object with value in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to add another object with value in data?

Something start like :

```
$data=[{name:"apple"}]
```

And i wanted output like this

```
$data=[{name:"apple",city:"gotham"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont try and build JSON manually, create a PHP data structure that you want and then use `json_encode()` to make it into a JSON String

```
$d = [(object)['name' => 'apple', 'city' => 'gotham']];

echo json_encode($d);
```

RESULT

```
[{"name":"apple","city":"gotham"}]
```

If some values already exists, you should decode it to a PHP data struture and then add to it and convert back to JSON String

```
$data='[{"name":"apple"}]';
$d = json_decode($data);
$d[0]->city = 'Gotham';

$data = json_encode($d);
```

RESULT

```
[{"name":"apple","city":"Gotham"}]
```

Comment: this one already declare first and shows.
[{name:"apple"}];

and how to add some object with value like the result i mention?
[{name:"apple",city:"gotham"}]